# Can IDA Pro on Linux disassemble a Windows PE (or Mac OS X app)?

Tags: ida, windows, tools, x86, linux

I am thinking of buying IDA Pro for my Linux programming environment after reverse engineering a bit with OllyDBG (under [WINE](http://winehq.org/))... But before I endorse into such a costly purchase I ask the following question(s):

- If I have native IDA Pro on Linux, can it disassemble/decompile a Windows PE (or Mac OS X apps as a bonus)?

- If not, when I multi boot Windows, can I download the Windows version of IDA on the Windows without purchasing it again?

## Motive

Some renowned programs I'd like to reverse (for fun) are Windows executables, so if it can't disassemble a Windows executable from Linux, I'll have to multi boot (tedious)

## Note

If it helps, I have a 32-bit machine with a x86 processor

Answer (score 10):

Current IDA versions (as of 6.5) are pretty much equivalent for all three platforms. You can disassemble [all file formats](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/file_formats.shtml) on all three platforms. You can definitely analyze PE and Mach-O files on Linux. Most debuggers are also [available on all platforms](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/index.shtml).

A couple of features are available only in the Windows version:

- WinDbg and Symbian debuggers
- WinCE debugging over ActiveSync
- PDB symbol parsing

Note: the last function is available on Linux and OS X if you can run the `win32_remote.exe` debugger on a Windows system/emulator.

Comment: I recommend using IDA Linux over IDA in Virtual Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Yes﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿

Comment: Is that intended to mean "Yes it can dissassemble Windows PE" or "Yes it can disassemble Mac OSX" or both?  It's a bit terse.

Comment: IDA Pro on any platform can disassemble Windows PE files and Mac OS X Mach-O files.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason that the first answer to this question was terse is that the information to answer your question is easily accessible on the Hex-Rays website.

Take a look at the [ordering page](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/order.shtml) on the website. There are .pdf forms that break out the pricing for IDA/IDA Pro. You must purchase the Linux and Windows version separately. As far as I understand, the disassemblers for IDA/IDA Pro are the same across platforms. You can see the differences in included disassemblers per edition [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/processors.shtml#starter). As one of the other answers to this question has pointed out, some of the integrated debuggers are not included on non-Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to mention:
Disassembling .NET applications is only possible in Windows Version. IDA uses some Microsoft dll's for parsing.

Another point:
As IDA is a 32bit application (even the 64bit disassembler) you always have to use remote debuggers for handling 64bit applications.

IDA works well for me with Wine under Linux. So I bought the Windows version to have all the features and use it either native under Windows or via Wine(Crossover) under Linux.

Comment: Not anymore, we implemented .NET parser for Linux and OS X a couple versions ago.